# Can't Set Resolution To 1080p

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution, xrandr

I've been trying to get Linux running on my PC for three days now and have everything worked out except for my resolution. After installing the latest compatible drivers from nvidia for my gtx 960 I still don't have a 1920x1080 option in the display settings. My monitor shows up as "Unkown" and in windows it shows up as "Generic non-pnp" but I can still set it to 1080p in windows. I've tried using xrandr to add a new mode but it always gives me the "X Error of failed request:BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)" error. I have no xorg config file (heard you don't need it any more anyway?) and running nvidia-xconfig tells me it's unable to locate/open the x configuration file. I've installed Ubuntu MATE and Mint and have had the same problem. It's also worth noting that when I plug in my projector, it detects it and displays the correct name and I can set it to 1080p.

Answer (score 1):

It is a wild guess, but you are not by any chance using a VGA video cable are you? Many VGA cables (even new ones in the shop now) are not fully wired, with the digital return link from monitor to video card missing. Then the monitor cannot be identified and a generic driver is selected, not supporting high resolutions. For VGA pin-out see http://pinouts.ws/db15-vga-pinout.html. My Nvidia 6800 series card needs at least pin 12 to be wired (and **not** connected to any of the ground pins, as is often the case).
Although a different type, so it doesn't compare to your situation: currently this Nvidia card works on 2560 x 1600 resolution (DVI-D interface) in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and 16.04 LTS without any problems, just plug and play.

Answer (score 0):

It is more than a year that NVIDIA drivers are problematic on my computer.  I have tried many things, as exposed in various posts, but this matter changes at quick pace.  Some tricks I found useful, though over the various versions of NVIDIA drivers, kernel version, and so on are the following:

1. Open the 'Parameters' window (you can achieve this, for instance, by
   right clicking on the Desktop and selecting to adjust the
   background).  Don't ask me why but it sometimes solves the problem
   instantly (sometimes with an ugly black rectangle around the windows).
2. Back and forth to terminal: Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get the terminal 1 and
   then Ctrl + Alt + F7 to go back to graphical screen.
3. Restart the graphical part: Ctrl+Alt+F1, login in and type `sudo service lightdm restart`.  In newer version of Ubuntu, there is probably another way to do that but it works at least until 16.04.
4. Last resort that I use: reboot the PC.  When I see a splash screen announcing 'NVIDIA', it is good news, the resolution generally is what it needs to.

Further, you can play with the various drivers (have a look at others posts for this. Good luck.
`